# Counting the number of possible matchups for teams

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

A tournament has 16 teams. How many ways are there to match up the teams in 8 pairs? Is it (16 choose 2)(14 choose 2)(12 choose 2)(10 choose 2)(8 choose 2)(6 choose 2)(4 choose 2)(2 choose 2)?

Comment: You have counted the number of ways to pick teams to be labelled Team 1, Team 2, and so on. Overcount by a factor of $8!$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. It is only 15*13*...*1, or 15!!

We consider one of the teams. It has 15 choices for its partner
Then consider another of the remaining 14 teams. It has 13 choices
Continue doing this, until we only get 1 choice

so the answer is 15*13*...*1=15!!.

Comment: Thank you. Ah. That makes sense. Once the first two teams have been selected, the third team only has 14 other teams it can possibly play against. So, it would be 15 * 13 * 11 * 9 * 7 * 5 * 3 * 1 = 2,027,205.

Comment: I am just curious - what made you think that it is 16choose 2 times etc. ? I just wanted to know so maybe we could help you avoid those kind of mistakes again.

Comment: Since the question was from the same section that had the flag question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057136/different-flag-signal-questions), I thought the same solution would be the same.

Comment: The difference there is that one of the teams is already "set" when forming a pair. It is not like the other one where you are matching the flags with colors.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still trying to wrap my head around all of this. =)